# Nginx forward ssl but not port 80

Tags: nginx, ssl, portforwarding

I am running a web service (with an SSL certificate) in a Docker container on port 8080, which I am forwarding to SSL port 443 (using [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707175/forward-nginx-8080-port-to-80) and it works correctly.

The issue is that if I go to http://mysite.domain I get the Nginx landing page, which I don't want, how do I stop that from happening please?

Below is my current configuration from nginx.conf

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl_certificates/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl_certificates/key.pem;

        server_name mysite.domain www.mysite.domain;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Readl-Port $server_port;
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding a rule for port 80 with no luck:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: You can simply add another listen directive `listen 80;`

Comment: @IVOGELOV If I add the listen 80; I still get the landing page, do I need to add a rule to redirect 80?

Comment: You seem to have added a new `server` block. In this case you will have to duplicate the `location` block with the `proxy_` directives. Or you can simply add the `listen 80;` directive to your existing `server` block.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Sorry for being dumb, but how do you differentiate http and https?  Would you be able to post an example please?

Comment: To differentiate between HTTP and HTTPS traffic - you will specify (or not) the `ssl` flag on the `listen` directive.